# Is it safe to reinterpret_cast<const char*> any struct that starts with a char[size] member?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, reinterpret-cast

Suppose I have 2 different structs:

```
struct A {
    char a_name[512];
    ...              // A struct data
}

struct B {
    char b_name[256];
    ...              // B struct data
}
```

Given `std::string name`, I need to check if an object (be it `A` or `B`) exists in a container. As both `A` and `B` start with a `char[size]` member which is the name I'm looking for to compare, I tried the following:

```
// T is a template parameter which is always an object of type A or B
           ↓ 
for (const T& item : container)
    if (name == reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&item))
```

It does work as expected. I read the object as if it was an array of chars, but as `A.a_name` and `B.b_name` are guaranteed to be null terminated, I don't read what I shouldn't... or do I? Can the code above produce undefined behaviour? Can it produce any error that I'm not taking into account? If so, how can I then approach this task?

I cannot modify `A` or `B`. I chose not to overload operator== for each class because `A` and `B` are actually many more different structs which have that structure I described above (`char[size]` + some more data).

Comment: what is `T`?  It looks like A and B have no common base class, so there is no possible `T`?

Comment: Reopened the question, for the duplicate is clearly wrong. It points to a question which asks about `reinterpret_cast`ing to non-char* type, and this makes the whole lot of a difference.

Comment: `// T is an object of type A or B` ?? How so? What is the type of actual container you are dealing with?

Comment: @ChrisDodd `T` represents the type of a template function, not a parent class or something. A and B are completely unrelated apart from having its first member `char[]`

Comment: @SergeyA Thank you for reopening it, I was confused ^^". The container is a `std::vector<T>`, while T is a template parameter. I can provide a little bit more of code if that makes it more clear

Comment: If `T` is a template parameter, than your function which iterates over container has to be a template. And if is, there is no need to `reinterpet_cast`, you can simply ask for a member of an object. You can either be sophisticated and do `if constexpr` to select a member name, or do yourself a favor and just name the member identically in both classes.

Comment: If you use this kind of pointer punning to the first non-static data member — *which is completely legit* — you may want to add some paranoia `static_assert` to make sure the classes abide by [`is_standard_layout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout).  Because it is likely that somewhere along the way, someone will add something to make them non-compliant.  Too bad you can't reflect to ensure the first non-static data member decays to a `char const*`.

Answer (score 6):

Your code should be safe if your classes are standard layout classes.

At the end of the section [class.members], we have

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its address is the same as the address of its first non-static data member if that member is not a bit-field. ... [Note: The object and its first subobject are pointer-interconvertible]

The section on Compound Types, [basic.compound], says

> If two objects are *pointer-interconvertible*, then they have the same address, and it is possible to obtain a pointer to one from a pointer to the other via a reinterpret_cast.

However, you can get rid of the `reinterpret_cast` entirely by creating a helper function to return the proper field.

```
const char *GetName(const A &a) {
    return a.a_name;
}

const char *GetName(const B &b) {
    return b.b_name;
}
// ...
for (const T& item : container)
    if (name == GetName(item))
```

There are variations on this, including `GetName` begin a template function that returns a specific field, with specific implementations for types that have a different field name.